# Randomly Split a Bar Into Beats

Tags: randomized-algorithms, sets, greedy-algorithms

So I'm writing a software that generates random MIDI tracks based on a given mode, tonal etc.

As for now the randomisation works on tones building sequences of equal duration.
What I'd like to do is also randomise the duration of each note in a sequence, but at the same time I'd like it to fit with the time signature. This in order to orchestrate the whole piece with chord progressions, mode / tonal changes etc.

I tried two different approaches so far:

### 1 Greedy Approach

Calculating the maximum amount of beats multiplying the bar size for 64 and then sequentially "consuming" this value.

```
possibleDurations = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
maxBeats = barSize * 64

white(maxBeats > 0) {
    chosenDuration = random(possibleDurations where possibleDuration <= maxBeats)
    maxBeats = maxBeats - chosenDuration
}
```

This works fine, but the problem is that, being greedy, it often leaves shorter beats at the end of the bar which is unwanted as I'd like it to be as random as possible.

### 2 Splitting Approach

Recursively split the bar in 1-2-4 and then decide wether to split each segment in 1-2-4 and so on. This also works fine and doesn't "accumulate" short beats like the Greedy Approach, but still has patterns like frequent consecutive same-length beats in multiples of 2 etc.

How could I solve this problem with a "truly random" approach, meaning that all possible configurations could possibly be found and there are no implementation-specific patterns?

Comment: Try the greedy approach, but shuffling which beat gets the new random duration each time.

Comment: Possibly relevant, but probably more complicated than you want or need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161406/781723